# join with laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

how can I write this statement with laravel?

```
$totalSpend= DB::
select
('
  SUM(mt_subscription.total_w_tax) 
  FROM companies 
  INNER JOIN   mt_client ON companies.id = mt_client.company_id 
  INNER JOIN mt_subscription on mt_client.client_id = mt_subscription.client_id 
  WHERE mt_client.company_id = 1
');
```

the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
DB::table('companies AS cm')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(sub.total_w_tax)'))
        ->join('mt_client AS cl','cm.id','=','cl.company_id')
        ->join ('mt_subscription AS sub','cl.client_id','=','sub.client_id')
        ->where('cl.company_id','=','1')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use DB::raw when you have a aggregate function

> $totalSpend= DB::select(DB::raw(SUM(mt_subscription.total_w_tax)) FROM
>   companies  INNER JOIN  mt_client  ON  companies.id =
>   mt_client.company_id  INNER JOIN mt_subscription  ON
>   mt_client.client_id = mt_subscription.client_id WHERE
>   mt_client.company_id = 1');